# Хранение изображений в бд

Tags: php, база-данных, vue.js, img

Подскажите как именно хранить изображения в бд (MySql) и отправлять их на фронт в json. Стек Laravel+ vue и как нужно настроить webpack?

Answer (score 5):

Само изображения Вам хранить в бд не надо. Это будет весить слишком много и сильно замедлит её работу.

Вместо этого сохраняйте путь до файла и по запросу отдавайте в json просто ссылку на него.

Для этого Вам нужно настроить в Вашем веб-сервере (nginx, apache, etc...) путь к публично доступным файлам.

На фронте, соответственно, просто вставляете полученную ссылку.

Answer (score 0):

Если уж очень нужно, то изображения можно хранить в base64 кодировке